# How do you embed most recent youtube with a channel id?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I know the following code works for any channel that has a username. Eg: (NerdAlert)

```html
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=NerdAlert" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Eg: http://codepen.io/liquidvisual/pen/oZxORy

However, I can't get this to work with my channel - which doesn't have a user name like the above. I only have access to a channel ID, and this doesn't work.

Comment: If this channelId "UCZFw_xWFLjR6gwyX-LRdRuw" is the one that you are reffering that doesn't have a name. Well if you check it with [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZFw_xWFLjR6gwyX-LRdRuw), it has a name of "liquidv" that you can use with embedding.

Comment: @KENdi Thanks that actually works. How can I make it work for this channel, where the name is "Dan & Mitch" - I tried this in the codepen but it returned the wrong result: youtube.com/channel/UC4S74VhUhaL1HGv3kxYyH6Q

Comment: If the channel does not have a "legacy" name, it will not work. They are called with the "forUsername" property in the api instead of the ID property. Legacy names also never had any space's in them.

Comment: @Tempus So if a channel name is **not** legacy and does **not** have a username (due to less than 100 subs) you have no access to the API in this way?

Comment: A "legacy username" has nothing to do with sub's. A "legacy username" is what YouTube used to use for channels, but after 2012 (I think) they moved to using ID's only. All older channel's will still have the legacy name if you know what is was to use it. Custom URL's will not, and do not work the same. Sorry to say, but no you don't have access in that way.

Comment: Just had a thought, that you could make a "playlist" of the selected channels video's.  Not sure if there is a limit on how many video's can be in a playlist, but might be a way round a few things for you.

Answer (score 1):

As tested [[here]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) , it would seem that the embedded player has no saport at the moment for "Channel ID's".

So I would put a bug request in if I was you.

As a work around. you can use the iFrame embed Api from [[here]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

In the "videoId" part, you can put a coma separated string of all the video id's. That will then act like what you wanted.

Depending on your need's, if you require a more dynamic one for a site,
 then you will need to have some code in place to collect and populate the player.

First is to get the uploaded list from the channel.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=[THE_CHANNEL_ID]&key=[apiKey]
```

Change "id=[THE_CHANNEL_ID]" to "forUsername=[LEGACY_USERNAME]" if required.

Then grab in code the upload's playlist from

```
[items] => [0] => [contentDetails] => [relatedPlaylists] => [uploads]
```

Then you can take it and plug that into the ...../v3/playlistItems api call.

Here you will need to have a loop setup to collect all your videoID's.
Then you can put them into a string to load into the player.
Also note that if your selected channel has more than 50 video's, then you will need to page through the results a few times to get a full list.

Also note that some channels can have well over 500 uploads. So selecting a limit might be a good idea.